# How can I format a NTFS drive from DOS?

Tags: ntfs, formatting, ms-dos

I want to format my pc from DOS while the operating system fall and the type of drives are NTFS.

When I try to format it these messages appear:

```
invalid drive specification
   format not supported in drive C:
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove NTFS file system and Reformat with Win 98/Me Boot Disk

> Format with a Win98/Me Startup disk.
>
> Use a Windows 98/Me startup disk to delete the non-dos partition.
>   Boot from Startup Disk.
>
> Load FDISK by typing "fdisk.exe" at the "A" prompt without the quotes.
>
> Say yes to large disk support  ...........? [Y]  ENTER
>
> Enter choice #3 to "Delete partition or Logical Dos Drive"   Press ESC to return to FDISK options
>
> Enter #4 to "Delete Non-DOS Partition". Select the Non-DOS partition by typing the number and then ENTER. Press ESC to return to FDISK options. Note you cannot delete a NON-DOS partition located inside an Extended partition. You can use the DOS utility called delpart.exe from a DOS boot up.
>
> Reboot with startup disk and load FDISK.
>
> Say yes to Large disk support as above.
>
> Enter choice #1 Press ESC to return to FDISK options
>
> When asked if you want to use the maximum size for the partition and make it active, type Y if you want to use the whole drive, or N if you want to set a maximum sized for the partition.
>
> After setting the size, reboot.
>
> If you want to install another OS; after reboot:  Type format X:  at the A: prompt; where X is the drive/partition letter designation.
>
> If you want to reinstall XP clean. After setting the size, reboot, remove the disk from the floppy drive and insert the XP CD in the CD drive.
>
> Boot from the XP CD and do a clean install to the new partition.

.

[Source of Information](http://www.michaelstevenstech.com/format_XPnojs.htm#98bd)

.

You cannot format NTFS using a DOS boot disc, only FAT, use a XP installation CD as suggested earlier to format NTFS.

.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than DOS, you could boot to the Windows Recovery Console and use the commands available there. You can find this on your Windows install disc. HELP will show a list of commands.

Answer (score 1):

Use [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) instead.  You simply burn a CD or create a USB stick, and you can perform all manner of operations on your disk partitions, including formatting, resizing, creating, and others.  It's **very** handy.

Comment: +1 Also PartitionMagic (for DOS) if you have it.

Answer (score 0):

dos dosen't have native NTFS support - there IS a driver that might be usable that avira used to have called ntfs4dos, but its no longer supported. Installing that MIGHT make the drive usable. You're better off, frustrationwise using a minimalist linux live cd and its copy of fdisk and mkdosfs to do the job tho

Comment: ntfs4dos is something i've used, i remember using it in 2006, maybe it was around earlier  perhaps before avira was out there. maybe avira bought it.. there is also NTFSPRO from sysinternals. As you suggest,  I think it just provides read/write access, it doesn't add any new commands, so FORMAT would still only do FAT16 or FAT32 not NTFS.